# Android resource not found exception when converting a String to Integer

Tags: java, android, casting

This is not a duplicate of the questions titled `Android Resource not found exception`.

I have a recycler view in my app. I have a couple of buttons in the card view and when the button is clicked I am getting the unique ID associated with each card and passing it to a function in my fragment for further processing.

The `onClick` on my recycler view is as follows:

```
  if( v.getId() == butAccept.getId()){

                String x = String.valueOf(dataSet.get(getAdapterPosition()).getMeetId());
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),x,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myFrag.showToast(x);
            }
```

When this code executes the unique ID associated with the cards are displayed correctly in the `Toast`.

```
  public void showToast(String x){
        Integer MeetId = Integer.parseInt(x);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),MeetId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

When the `showToast()` is executed I am getting a `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1` error. When I `Toast` the unique ID without casting it to integer I am getting the correct integer. If I convert it to `Integer` before toasting then I am getting a error as mentioned above. I am sure that the `getMeetId()` function is returning an Integer.

What might be causing this problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: guess how many times "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1" was already asked here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The makeText(..) method is looking for a String from your resource directory with the integer ID supplied in the method.

In order to solve this, replace the following:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MeetId ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

With:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "" + MeetId ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

By looking at the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)) you can see why this would happen.

Using resource ID:

```
public static Toast makeText(Context context, @StringRes int resId, @Duration int duration)
                            throws Resources.NotFoundException {
    return makeText(context, context.getResources().getText(resId), duration);
}
```

Using String:

```
public static Toast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, @Duration int duration) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the method `makeText` then you'll notice that you are calling the `Toast.makeText(context, resId, duration);` method, which takes as the second argument a `String` resource id. As you are calling it with an Integer the system will look for a string resource in your strings.xml file with that ID. So don't parse the String to an integer, but just show your `String` instead in your `Toast`:

```
public void showToast(String x){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguments required for toast is:

`Toast(context, String, Length(integer))`

So don't convert your string to Integer. Directly display it in toast.

```
 Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),x,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```